# How to use this json variable in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i want to get data in json and use them in my program. i use these codes:

```
public class Test
        {
            public class Coord
            {
                public double lon { get; set; }
                public double lat { get; set; }
            }

            public class Weather
            {
                public int id { get; set; }
                public string main { get; set; }
                public string description { get; set; }
                public string icon { get; set; }
            }

            public class Root
            {
                public Coord coord { get; set; }
                public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
                public string name { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

i know how to use simple variables like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test.Root>(jsontest);
double myLon = obj.coord.lon;
```

my question is how to use variables inside weather class because its defined in list! for example i want to store "icon" in a string variable. im new in C#, help me please.

Comment: It should have deserialized any applicable `Weather` objects as well. Did it not do that?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: as i said double myLon = obj.coord.lon; works fine but when i write string myDescription = obj.weather.description; it doesnt work and i get an error in my program.

Comment: Well you do have to use it like a list; as in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since weather is of type `List'1`, you have to access it like a list using an index:

```
double icon = obj.weather[0].icon
```

or using linq:

```
double icon = obj.weather.First().icon
```

You can have multiple `Weather` objects in that list, so treat it accordingly.

Comment: Especially on the second one, you should use `FirstOrDefault` in case the list is empty (unless you are OK with catching the exception).

Comment: FirstOrDefault().icon would still throw an `NullReferenceException` if the list is empty.  Point being, don't use linq unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Ah; excellent point. It is unlikely the JSON would have an *empty* list, it would just be null.